# how to create a window with title less border? when the window is maximized it should not cover the task bar

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to create a window using win32 without title bar. The border should resize the window. But when I maximize the window it covers the task bar also and I don't want to cover task bar. How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* if a window is in MAXIMIZED state, it doesn't cover the standard taskbar - however, you can force your window fullscreen without it being maximized. To demonstrate:

```
// Force window to cover the taskbar...
case WM_SIZE:
  if( wParam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED )
  {
    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_RESTORE ); // not MAXIMIZED any more

    // show on top at 1920x1080 size
    SetWindowPos( hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,1920,1080,SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
  }
  break;
```

Note that this does have all the problems associated with a window being TOPMOST!

**Alternatively...**
If you have a window without menubar which covers the taskbar when maximized and **you want the taskbar to still be visible** then resize the window to the screen work area:

```
HMONITOR hmon= MonitorFromWindow(hDlg, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST );
MONITORINFO moninfo;
moninfo.cbSize= sizeof(moninfo);
GetMonitorInfo(hmon, &moninfo);

SetWindowPos(hWnd,0, moninfo.rcWork.left, moninfo.rcWork.top,
                     moninfo.rcWork.right,moninfo.rcWork.bottom, SWP_NOZORDER );
```

Note: you do not want to set such a window to MAXIMIZED, just use the above to resize it to fullscreen minus taskbar (if the window does not have a title bar/system menu then it cannot be moved by the user, so it works like being maximized).

Comment: Actually i need window without title bar and with border so i'am using this API to create   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, 
        0, 
        WS_BORDER , 
        10, 50, 1000, 600, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        hInstance, 
        NULL); 


 
   SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, 0); 
   SetWindowLong(hWnd,   GWL_STYLE,WS_BORDER|WS_THICKFRAME|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX); so in this case the window is covering task bar also.

Comment: Do you want your window on top of the task bar or not ??

Comment: No , window should not on top of task bar.

Comment: This code is working fine But here border is also visible,,, like normal window when we maximize border should not visible.

Comment: Your earlier message said you called:  SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE,WS_BORDER|WS_THICKFRAME|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX); which is why you have a border !!!

Comment: Actually i want window without title bar and with border so i created window and i removed title bar using this Api       SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, 0) then i used this ::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE,WS_BORDER|WS_THICKFRAME|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX) to have only border but when we maximize it should work like normal App , i mean border should not come, and when it resize border should be there. how can we achieve this . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Taskbar will lower itself (let itself be covered) when any fullscreen window without title bar is shown. This is to support scenarios such as games, flash videos, Power Point presentations etc.

Any hack you do will eventually be overridden as you interact with other windows in the system.

The best you can do is what TonyWilk says, which is to use the screen work area (or desktop work area) and resize your window to only that size when the user wants to maximize it. Do note, this will need to be calculated each time you want to maximize to handle issues such as the desktop work area changing, or your window getting moved to another monitor.